# Where to store access token(JWT) on SPA when server is on another domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, security, jwt

My frontend is on domain1 and backend is on domain2, meaning communication is cross site. On user authentication server responds with JWT token. Question is: Where do I safely store that token client-side?

I cant use cookies since domains differ and local/session storage is unsafe? How do I store it safely and preferably have it persist site refresh?

There are many similar questions here but all recommend http only cookie which I can't use in this situation since domains are different and any extra server or proxy or redirect is impossible (out of my control). So i apologize if i skipped question that already answers this specific scenario.

I'm familiar with general overview of subject but i don't know solution to this **specific** case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Storing your JWT token in cookie or storage isnt unsace. On your server side you give your token an expire date and if the user try to access something with the same token after its expire date it wont work. Even if the user keep the toke like forever somewhere on his PC that token will be useless cuz its date expired

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good solution for this?  I've been unable to find a way that is both secure, yet persistentent.

Comment: @gabriel.hayes that is both extremely bad advice, and entirely untrue.

Storing the JWT in anything other than a httpOnly cookie is a surefire way to ensure that any successful XSS attack has access to all our users' credentials.